# Changing CPU to GPU destroy the 3D view look of a normal map blender 2.75rc2?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I use win 7 and blender 2.75rc2 and when I change the render to GPU then the normal map looks often destroyed and it ends that I see the  the seams on the model and a bad shading  !

1.

I use hd 7970 and that full featured so any one can confirm that ?

2.

i try to bake the normal map again but some Maps work some not .
Some baked normal Maps works different for example when  I change to non color in the Image texture node .

Some time it happens that they  Maps  have  lighter color goes pink sometime more blue , after saving to png Most time light pink but sometimes I can save the deeper blue non color baked normal map and blender preview show png with this Deep blue normal map.

i change nothing  wether  Position of high or low res model or on the baking Setting..

i can't upload the file sry bad conection only picture...
is it possible to upload direct a picture in this question or only links ?

Thx 
Best regard ...happy blending

Comment: It might be an issue with the AMD card... can you show images that display the issue? Uploading your file would be helpful so other users can try it on Nvida cards and get to a definitive answer.